# For loop being skipped after bubble sort function

Tags: c, function, for-loop, structure, bubble-sort

I am making a  sorting program for a final assignment. It takes the account number, last name, and balance of the account and sorts it in ascending order based on the account number. The issue I am having with my program is that once it gets to the for loop to output the information, it completely skips it. I believe it might have to do with my bubble sort function, but I am not sure how to fix it. We haven't been taught quick sort, so I am not using it. I am receiving an  error: incompatible type for argument 1 of `sort', but I cannot change the array to type struct without it causing more issues. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Define structure */

struct account
{
    int number;
    char full_name[30];
    float balance;
};

/* Function prototype */

void sort (int[], int);

/* Begin main function */

int main()
{

    /* Declare variables */

    struct account person[5];
    int x=0, i=0, count=0;

    printf("Enter account number, last name, and balance.\n");
    printf("Enter -999 to end input:\n\n");

    /* Create loop for user information */
    while(1)
    {

            scanf("%i", &person[x].number);
            if(person[x].number == -999) /*Break when -999 is input */
            {
                count = x;
                break;
            }


            if(person[x].number < 1 || person[x].number >1000)
            {
                printf("***Invalid account number. Please enter 1 - 1000 or -999 to exit***\n");
                x--;  
                continue;
            }

            scanf("%s", person[x].full_name);
            scanf("%f", &person[x].balance);

            if(person[x].balance < 0)
            {
            printf("*** Invalid balance amount. Please enter a positive value. ***\n");
            x--;
            continue;
            }
    }/* End of while loop */

    /* Call to sort function to sort information */

    sort(person[x].number, count);

    /* Display the information in ascending order */

    printf("ACCOUNT\tLAST NAME\tBALANCE\n");

    /* Create for loop to output the sorted information */

    for(x=0; x < count; x++)
    {
        printf("%d\t%s\t%f\n",person[x].number,person[x].full_name,person[x].balance);

    } /* End of for loop */
}/* End of main */

/* Start sort function */

void sort(int p[], int count)
{
    /* Declare variables.*/
 char changed = 'T'; /* a "flag" to indicate if a swap was made.*/
 int x, temp;
 while (changed == 'T') 
 {
    changed = 'F';
    /* Create for loop for swaping information */
    for (x = 0; x < count-1; x++)
    {
        if ( p[x] > p[x + 1])
        {
            /* Swap needs to be made.*/
            temp = p[x];
            p[x] = p[x+1];
            p[x+1] = temp;
 /* Set flag indicating that a swap was made. This ensures that */
 /* processing will continue, until nothing needs to be swapped. */
            changed = 'T';
        }
    } /* end for loop */
 } /* end while loop*/
} /* end function sort */
```

Here is my output:

```
Enter account number, last name, and balance.
Enter -999 to end input:

10 Happy 55.00
15 Day 60.00
35 Man 75.00
-999
ACCOUNT LAST NAME       BALANCE
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I appreciate your assistance and the time you are taking to help!

Comment: You need, at some point in your input `while` loop, to increment the `x` (and, thus, `count`) variable. I don't see anywhere that you do this!

Comment: What do you think `sort(person[x].number, count);` does? Didn't the compiler give warnings or even errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first as mentioned in comments add `x++` at the end of your `while-loop` to scan data.

also you should know that by sending one member of struct (`number`) to your sort function , and sorting it , other members won't be sorted (only another number will be replaced with theirs).

also note here  `sort(person[x].number, count);` you are sending one element of member number from struct to function . while in declaration of function ,you said you will send an array of integer to it.

this should be `sort(person, count);` and in function deceleration you should 
 use `sort(struct account p[],int count);` also you have to change function by using `p[x].number`.

also note that to add `x++` at the end of your `while-loop` , you have to remove those `continue` , otherwise when you do `x--` you won't reach `x++`.

I wrote another sort function which I think is more logical.

```
struct account
{
    int number;
    char full_name[30];
    float balance;
};
void sort(struct account p[], int count);

int main()
{
    struct account person[5];
    int x = 0, i = 0, count = 0;

    printf("Enter account number, last name, and balance.\n");
    printf("Enter -999 to end input:\n\n");
    while (1)
    {
        scanf("%i", &person[x].number);
        if (person[x].number == -999) 
        {
            count = x;
            break;
        }

        if (person[x].number < 1 || person[x].number >1000)
        {
            printf("***Invalid account number. Please enter 1 - 1000 or -999 to exit***\n");
            x--;
            //remove continue
        }

        scanf("%s", person[x].full_name);
        scanf("%f", &person[x].balance);

        if (person[x].balance < 0)
        {
            printf("*** Invalid balance amount. Please enter a positive value. ***\n");
            x--;
            //remove continue
        }
        x++;//add x++ 
    }

    sort(person, count);//new function sort

    printf("ACCOUNT\tLAST NAME\tBALANCE\n");

    for (x = 0; x < count; x++)
    {
        printf("%d\t%s\t%f\n", person[x].number, person[x].full_name, person[x].balance);

    } 
}


void sort(struct account p[], int count)
{
    char changed = 'T'; 
    int x, temp;
    float btemp;
    char ntemp[30];// btemp for balance and ntemp for full_name
    while (changed == 'T')
    {
        changed = 'F';
        for (x = 0; x < count - 1; x++)
        {
            if (p[x].number > p[x + 1].number)
            {
                temp = p[x].number;
                p[x].number = p[x + 1].number;
                p[x + 1].number = temp;

                btemp = p[x].balance;
                p[x].balance = p[x + 1].balance;
                p[x + 1].balance = btemp;

                strcpy(ntemp , p[x].full_name);
                strcpy(p[x].full_name , p[x + 1].full_name);
                strcpy(p[x + 1].full_name , ntemp);
                changed = 'T';

            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Hanie! I did what you said and cleaned up my program. Now it is running perfectly. We didn't learn much about sorting structures, so you taught me a lot.